# Select column value and next highest column value in SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, presto

I have two columns: userid and date_accessed. I want to have a third column which, for each row (each userid and date_accessed combo), returns the next highest date for date_accessed. Right now my query is like:

```
SELECT 
   userid, 
   date_accessed AS first_date,
   (SELECT date_accessed
    FROM table
    WHERE date_accessed > first_date
    ORDER BY date_accessed ASC
    LIMIT 1) AS second_date
FROM table
```

But this isn't working — could someone please help me understand why?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a subquery, the correct syntax would be:

```
SELECT t.userid, t.date_accessed AS first_date,
       (SELECT t2.date_accessed
        FROM table t
        WHERE t2.date_accessed > t.date_accessed
        ORDER BY t2.date_accessed ASC
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS second_date
FROM table t;
```

Note that the column references are all qualified with their table names.

If you want this *per user*, you need a correlated clause for that as well:

```
SELECT t.userid, t.date_accessed AS first_date,
       (SELECT t2.date_accessed
        FROM table t
        WHERE t2.userid = t.userid AND t2.date_accessed > t.date_accessed
        ORDER BY t2.date_accessed ASC
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS second_date
FROM table t;
```

If the dates are unique, you can use `LEAD()`:

```
select t.*,
       lead(date_accessed) over (partition by userid order by date_accessed)
from t;
```